# Compare two columns A and B to get data in 3 columns, C,D & E

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking for a VBA to compare two columns A and B to get data in 3 columns, C,D & E.

- C should have values that are in column A but not in column B.
- D should have values that are in column B but not in column A.
- E should have values that are in both column A and B.

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D | Column E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | 4 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |  |  | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |  |  | 3 |
| 5 | 3 |  |  |  |

[image]

This is the code I have currently that I want to enhance.

```
Sub Compare1() 'Excel VBA to compare 2 lists.
    Dim ar as Variant
    Dim var()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Long
    
    ar = Range("a1").CurrentRegion 'Change Input to suit
    ReDim var(1 To UBound(ar, 1), 1 To 1)
    
    With Createobject("scripting.dictionary")
        .comparemode = 1

        For i = 1 To UBound(ar, 1)
            .Item(ar(i, 2)) = Empty
        Next

        For i = 1 To UBound(ar, 1)
            If Not .exists(ar(i, 1)) Then
                n = n + 1
                var(n, 1) = ar(i, 1)
            End If
        Next
    End With

    [D1].Resize(n).Value = var 'Change output to suit  
End Sub
```

Comment: Why VBA? Seem to me like you need a few formulae.

Comment: Use match(), at least that is what I would go with and will work for all the scenarios you state.

Answer (score 0):

See my solution below and explaining comments in the code.

It uses `Application.Match` which returns an error if a value cannot be found. We can use that to determine if a value is present in the other column. If so they are in both otherwise they are unique to that column. Then we just need to push them to the desired output column.

The entire calculation is done with arrays for faster processing. Arrays are then written to the cells.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Compare()
    Dim ws As Worksheet  ' define worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Const HeaderColumns As Long = 1  ' define how many header columns there are
    
    ' get last used rows in column A and B
    Dim LastRowA As Long
    LastRowA = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim LastRowB As Long
    LastRowB = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' read column A and B into arrays
    Dim InputDataA() As Variant
    InputDataA = ws.Range("A1").Resize(LastRowA, 1).Value2
    
    Dim InputDataB() As Variant
    InputDataB = ws.Range("B1").Resize(LastRowB, 1).Value2
    
    ' Define output ranges
    Dim OutRngOnlyInA As Range
    Set OutRngOnlyInA = ws.Range("C1").Resize(LastRowA, 1)
    
    Dim OutRngOnlyInB As Range
    Set OutRngOnlyInB = ws.Range("D1").Resize(LastRowB, 1)
    
    Dim OutRngInBoth As Range
    Set OutRngInBoth = ws.Range("E1").Resize(Application.Min(LastRowA, LastRowB), 1)
    
    ' get output ranges into arrays
    Dim OutOnlyInA() As Variant
    OutOnlyInA = OutRngOnlyInA.Value2
    
    Dim OutOnlyInB() As Variant
    OutOnlyInB = OutRngOnlyInB.Value2
    
    Dim OutInBoth() As Variant
    OutInBoth = OutRngInBoth.Value2
    
    ' define counters for output arrays
    Dim cntOnlyInA As Long, cntOnlyInB As Long, cntInBoth As Long
    cntOnlyInA = HeaderColumns
    cntOnlyInB = HeaderColumns
    cntInBoth = HeaderColumns
    
    ' loop through input data
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 + HeaderColumns To Application.Max(UBound(InputDataA), UBound(InputDataB))
        If iRow <= UBound(InputDataA) Then
            If IsError(Application.Match(InputDataA(iRow, 1), InputDataB, 0)) Then
                ' cannot be found in B so it is only A
                cntOnlyInA = cntOnlyInA + 1
                OutOnlyInA(cntOnlyInA, 1) = InputDataA(iRow, 1)
            Else
                ' can be found in B so it is in A and B
                cntInBoth = cntInBoth + 1
                OutInBoth(cntInBoth, 1) = InputDataA(iRow, 1)
            End If
        End If
        
        If iRow <= UBound(InputDataB) Then
            If IsError(Application.Match(InputDataB(iRow, 1), InputDataA, 0)) Then
                ' cannot be found in A so it is only B
                cntOnlyInB = cntOnlyInB + 1
                OutOnlyInB(cntOnlyInB, 1) = InputDataB(iRow, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next iRow

    ' write output to cells
    OutRngOnlyInA.Value2 = OutOnlyInA
    OutRngOnlyInB.Value2 = OutOnlyInB
    OutRngInBoth.Value2 = OutInBoth
End Sub
```

[image]